# Looking to filter query based on last two digits in price column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run an analysis that looks at conversion changes based on price point. To do this, I am trying to bucket prices based on last two digits. How would i go about filtering based on the last two digits in the where clause? I'll want to filter prices ending in .99, (.25,50,.75,), .%0, etc.

Comment: What is the data type of the price column?

Comment: numeric (20,2) . @nofinator

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help.  Generally speaking you'll want to use `CASE` with grouping to create the buckets.

Comment: @AaronDietz im running each as an individual pull so i was just going to filter in the where clause. As far as sample data goes, I have a list of prices in the price column of my table and i want to see which price gets the most clicks. So as a first step, I want to pull data for all prices ending in $.99. Then I would rerun that same query but instead of prices ending in $.99, I would want to see it for prices ending in 0 ($.10,$.20, etc. ) Does that make things more clear?

Answer (score 4):

Generally to filter by "last digits" one would use modulo operator `%`, that is rest of division.

For integers its meaning is clear: `123 % 100 = 23`, `123 % 10 = 3`. For any x being integer `x % 1 = 0` (as any integer is divisible by 1)

And it seems in Redshift it works for decimals as well:

`select 123.99 % 1 as cents;`

> cents
>
> 0.99

so `select price from table where price % 1 = 0.99` should return you all prices ending with `.99`, which we can easily verify:

```
with prices as (
  select 9.99 as price union 
  select 9.43 union
  select 0.99 union 
  select 2
)
select * 
from prices
where price % 1 = 0.99;
```

yields

```
price
9.99
0.99
```

Comment: this is very helpful. If I wanted to filter for all prices ending in 0 would it just be where price % 1 = 0.%0 ? @Mariusz Sakowski

Comment: Yes! Try it for yourself. You can also `SELECT price, price %1 as cents`.